Please give us some FAQ and comprehensive help articles about staging-grounds intended workflow
staging-ground seems to work out way better than the triage-queue, but the intended workflow for reviewers is still a bit clumsy and unclear, at least for me.
Specifically after editing a question (which is still unsufficient to do edits in plain markdown, and preview by default), adding comments using the available templates, I am unsure, what action I should choose to activate the Submit button.
Can we have some FAQ and help articles about this?

Note: we do have some help articles.

@AbdulAzizBarkat there is but it is rather unclear. I am honestly confused by the "As an asker, how do I use Staging Ground?" part. "Asker" is the one who wrote the question, but then there are bullets saying "An asker indicates that your post is ready to leave the Staging Ground" and "An asker indicates that your post needs some minor changes, ..." these are either typos or need severe clarification

I also don't understand "Require major changes:..." I thought I did that, but then the question was posted without major changes just to get closed.

I don't understand many things in that "review process", and that definitely needs to be clarified or fixed (e.g. one of my 1st questions was how to opt out that thing). I am still fine as curator for some specific tags, and to close/delete vote that stuff making it through that.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai it's easy - when you mark something as "Requires major changes" it means that the asker can't post it without modifying it significantly to address the comment you left ("requires major changes" also requires a comment). However, apparently a single other reviewer can just publish it. https://i.sstatic.net/gYAFwR8I.png

@VLAZ I tried that,  but must leave my own comment regarding that, even if one already exists. That would actually only produce noise with identical comments. Let's face it, that whole thing is far from "production ready", and I didn't agree to be involved by default.

@πάνταῥεῖ if the post is already in the major changes state you don't need to submit another review. If it's submitted for re-review and previous feedback is not addressed just decline re-evaluation. If it's in neither of those states the previous reviewer probably forgot to submit a review.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I think we can agree that the help articles arent sufficent yet. At least I didnt find where it explains the procedure you just explained.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I've agreed with the feature request from the start, my comment was just pointing out that we have some help articles. Are they great / sufficient? Probably not. ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: It looks like those 2 list entries have been corrected at some point since your original comment; they now both read "A reviewer indicates [...]" instead.
