We need Staging Ground reviewer onboarding before showing it in the question list
Questions shown in the staging ground appear in the top questions and similar pages. I don't necessarily disagree with that as it could be a good way to fix the scaling issue in principle.
However, I have one big issue with this: People browsing questions (even with 500+ reputation and having asked questions before) don't know how the Staging Ground works.
For example, I have seen a user asking for clarification in the Staging Ground without using the Requires Major Changes option and asked them to use that option in the future. As a response I was told they were just browsing questions and didn't know about the UI. They also posted about this afterwards (thank you a lot for your insights). This user is by far not the only one with that issue bringing me to this request. Until now, I have messaged >10 reviewers about that via https://chat.stackoverflow.com. Out of these users, >6 responded. Most of them were saying it's related to the Staging Ground being new/not knowing how to work with it in some form or the other (and the other one was confused/stopped by the locking system). They just didn't know better and were thankful about being corrected.
Please, make sure that reviewers are explained how the Staging Ground works before they are reviewing their first question, commenting or closing it, especially for reviewers that get to the Staging Ground using the top questions page or similar.
For example, I could imagine users getting some information on how the Staging Ground works along with the reviewer guidelines when they view their first question in the Staging Ground.
I could imagine this being in the form with a modal shown when opening a Staging Ground post the first time. This should include:

What is the Staging Ground (a place where askers can get their questions improved before them being public)
How to review questions

This includes the reviewer guidelines or at least a link to it


Explain that reviewers should select an action (like "Requires Major Changes") when reviewing a post as opposed to just commenting
Tell (especially higher-rep) reviewers to prefer "Requires Major Changes" over closing. If a post can be improved by the author so it would be considered fine for the site, it should probably not be closed in the Staging Ground.

Alternatively, I could also imagine the Staging Ground not appearing in these question lists by default and only showing up there once the user received some onboarding by viewing https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground once.
This way, we would still get a lot of reviewers seeing Staging Ground posts in the question list and these people understand how it works.

When I wrote Don't release and ignore it, this is the kind of issue I was talking about that shouldn't be ignored.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/430513/6296561

" When I wrote Don't release and ignore it, this is the kind of issue I was talking about that shouldn't be ignored. " - I mean... what did you expect? This is what SE does for a living. The SG was set up for failure the second onboarding was deprioritised  in favour of implementing the SG first (or rather completely ignored; I doubt onboarding was ever considered). We don't have enough reviewers because there isn't other forms of onboarding, and we have bad reviews and lots of confusion around locks because the SG itself doesn't have onboarding. SE has already set the SG on a crash course

See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396939/332043 for a primer on how SE does product releases - the SG is joining the list of hit-and-run deployed features soon enough

At some point someone has to wake up and realize: oh. People in the 21st century are lowest effort creatures. Maybe we shouldn't trust them to by their nature attempt to do the right thing.

To be honest, I tried to tell them to not ignore it after the release again and again hoping they would listen for once. I guess we will see how that works now.

@Gimby but... waking up and realizing things would require effort....

I just looked over the front page for a bit for things to review, opened the first Python question, and did exactly what you complain about here: left a comment suggesting a bunch of possible improvements and clarifications, but didn't "leave a review". Why? Because, as someone who knows Python but hasn't used the other tools involved in that question, I have enough expertise to be able to suggest improvements but not enough expertise to gauge if the question is already useful and answerable in its current state.

I suspect that experience of mine will be common for most users. It certainly will be for me, personally if I decide to use Staging Ground more. I know plenty of programming languages, but most questions involving those languages are also going to involve some libraries, APIs, or other tools I'm unfamiliar with; an inevitable consequence is that I'm able to pass superficial judgement on lots of questions and suggest improvements to them, but am not able, without serious effort, to judge if they are ultimately good/bad/useful/closeworthy. But to leave a review, I must make that judgment.

@Zoe "I doubt onboarding was ever considered". You are making it sound like you know what you are talking about, but you actually don't. It was very much considered, I was pushing hard for it while I was on the team, and had seen mockups and ideas in development around it. No idea where things stand right now though. And I don't think that you are a good judge of what can be considered ground for deeming the SG a failure, considering how many times you have done so throughout the history of the project.

@YaakovEllis Let me make one thing abundantly clear; I don't want the SG to fail. I've previously proposed something more or less identical to it many years ago. I believe that, as long as there's enough reviews and good onboarding for all parties, it can drastically increase quality and UX if implemented correctly. However, we don't have enough reviewers, and we don't really tell anyone how to use it. People stuck in purgatory when they really need an answer decreases UX, especially if the question is closed after auto-graduating. This is a bad combination

I've said this in chat, but my current prediction is that as the hype dies down, the number of excess reviewers drops back to the still too low baseline. That means longer wait times for askers, and more questions auto-graduating, likely to be closed shortly after. My definition of fail, while absolutely a hard word to use, is if the SG starts having  a negative impact on a significant number of users - and right now, that's exactly what it's set up for. As soon as management decides to reallocate resources, the SG is frozen with whatever situation it's in at the time

@Zoe I agree that it can be improved. However (and I was not free to say this while I was on staff) I and the whole team found your repeated predictions of failure (like you do above, and have done many times throughout the project) to be incredibly unsupportive and very demoralizing. And so far, all of your predictions of failure have not come true. (1/2)

Given that it's already in a bad place, and given history (especially now that staff has been downsized), the probability of the SG turning into a negative experience is high. There has already been askers abandoning the question because the SG is perceived as too complicated - exactly what onboarding is supposed to avoid, and one of the major ways the SG currently has a negative impact

@YaakovEllis "And so far, all of your predictions of failure have not come true." - we are barely a couple week in. My predictions are on the scale of several weeks for the initial signs and months for the long-term implications, and assumes everything is routed via the SG. For some reason, it still doesn't appear to have fully ramped up. Try again in 3-4 months, and we'll talk

@Zoe (contd 2/2) This is 2 weeks after initial release. The team will hopefully get to more things, like a better onboarding, more reports, badges, and all the cool stats and leaderboards that were planned. All of these can continue to improve it. There are ways of giving feedback without the doom and gloom. I urge you to reconsider your tone. This has been continuing from the very first announcement of SG.

@YaakovEllis And you've continued missing my point since that very first announcement. I've tried multiple angles, and none of them have been good enough. At a point, I gave up. I'm once again pointing to my answer with hard numbers on the reviewer deficit that was blatantly ignored. That is why I believe the SG will inevitably fail. When the reviewer deficit was ignored in advance, even when faced with numbers indicating it, I have zero faith the features dealing with that will ever be implemented, when day 0 is the single (1/2)

Biggest day requiring these features to be implemented. SE's general reactiveness to problems has historically been low. Failing to deal with that glaring problem in advance suggests it won't be addressed in the foreseeable future. I hope I'm wrong, but again, SE's track record is bad, and I'd rather be prepared to deal with the fallout than hope SE suddenly acquires the resources and knowledge required to not just fix the problem, but notice its existence - especially when I've explicitly pointed it out two years in advance, with not even a comment acknowledging the existence of the problem

@Zoe your words were ignored because they were about scale, yet you kept at it again and again. And all of the work up to this point was testing and improving workflow, NOT scale. My argument was that the comparisons to RQ were not appropriate, since it was given no avenue for recruitment of reviewers, while SG will have much more visibility from questions in listings. Half of the items in RQ are ignored (give or take) and it is not a failure. I do not think it a stretch that auto-grad rates can be better than that in the long term, with a much bigger positive effect felt on the site.

Hi @Zoe and Yaakov maybe it would be better if you would continue this in chat? (Can't believe I'm saying this to a mod and former staff :P) Maybe this chat room?

@YaakovEllis Everything we curators and moderators do is about scale. If you don't account for scale, whatever is implemented will fail. The queues aren't a failure because they aren't new. They were made for a different reality, and were never fixed. The SG seems to pretend that reality still exists when it doesn't. If scale was never the goal, there's nothing left to discuss, and the SG is indeed dead on arrival. Anything new not designed for scale will struggle at best and fail at worst - at least now I know that the reason isn't resource shortage, but intentional design

@Zoe The scale was of course a goal and it was of course designed for scale. Just that it wasnt actually tested before now. The beta was not about testing scale. Don't know any other way to put it. Scale is being tested now. And if there isn't the best onboarding in the first couple of weeks, it isn't the end of the world.

It may not be the end of the world but I do think the current lack of SG reviewer onboarding is somewhat of a big issue.

I'll just weigh in at this point, @dan1st - we're on week 2.  When we release a product in its early format, I don't think it's unusual that things like onboarding aren't included in the early release.  That's stuff that can be built in, collectively with community members who have strong opinions about what it should say, over time. Nobody has forgotten onboarding, or ignored it.  Nobody is pretending we don't need it.  We just haven't gotten to it yet.  If we are to release early and often, then sometimes those early releases will not be as feature rich as we would like for the long term.

I agree with that. But I fear other things being more important and it never being implemented and I'm uncertain about how much damage it does/already did.

We deployed two updates to work towards improving the onboarding experience for new reviewers.
Update 3 (Oct 22, 2024)
We've created the first onboarding video for reviewers. We'll update the help center article with a link and determine where else we can include this in-product.
Huge thanks to our product marketing and brand design teams for collaborating with us to create the video. We're working on a script for the next video focused on onboarding askers into Staging Ground.
Update 2
It was mentioned that new reviewers who see Staging Ground posts on the homepage/question list page may not understand what they should be doing.
As a result, their first interaction may not be going through to the landing page. To address this, we made an update to display the same onboarding illustration directly on the Staging Ground question page.
Update 1
We refreshed the onboarding illustration for new reviewers when they visit the https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/ landing page. Hopefully, the updated illustration and copy better aligns to 1) explain what Staging Ground is, 2) set expectations on how to interact with these posts (provide constructive feedback/guide new askers) and 3) understand the outcome reviewers are working towards (improving question quality)

Future updates

We are planning to create a short-form YouTube video (to support mixed media onboarding materials) to help onboard new reviewers that explains the "what", "why", and briefly how they should engage and interact (i.e. actions in the review panel)

As such, I will not be updating this post with status-completed yet.

Thank you for this update, this is (in my opinion) a huge improvement. Would it be possible to change the illustration to include something telling users to use "Requires Major Changes" for questions that could be improved/are not completely off-topic (including and especially but not limited to low-effort questions) in some way? See the "Tell (especially higher-rep) reviewers to prefer "Requires Major Changes" over closing. If a post can be improved by the author so it would be considered fine for the site, it should probably not be closed in the Staging Ground." point in my question.

Yeah, hopefully/probably better Onboarding now, but the "Give guidance, but don’t give the answer" (only available as 7th item in the Help Center) should be more prominent... Maybe 50% of the Posts I checked and tried to review in the SG (I pick only Posts with Status = New), already had Comments in them (but no Review submitted) and the previous Reviewer(s) (often with 10k-25k Rep) was/were already answering the Question. As soon as sbd starts answering their Qt in Comments, the OP doesn't care anymore about any Change(s) required and only reacts to the Answerer(s).

@dan1st thanks for the feedback, I'm leaning on keeping the illustration as broad and general for the purpose of focusing on explaining the "what" and the "why". I'll circle back with the designer to see what we can do for first time reviewers when they land on a question page for the reviewer panel.

@chivracq we have some planned work to address the comment but no action applied issue. This is related to onboarding but is being treated separately in a different set of work.

I think a video describing the most important things could also be useful with these issues (both that people should favor "Requires Major Changes" with a constructive comment over closing in many cases but also the thing about not giving the answer and probably also a few other things), especially if that video has good visibility together with the illustration/first visit page.

Yep, we will incorporate somewhere where there is prominence as well as in the help center

I wrote a MSO post on how to review questions in the Staging Ground, it may be a useful starting point for onboarding functionality/a future video.

@dan1st Thank you for your contributions! Does this make sense to add to and expand the current reviewer guidelines help center article?
I'll be updating my original answer with the reviewer YouTube video that was uploaded last week. We tried to keep the video as concise as possible and incorporating some of the things you mentioned in your original post.

Takes quite a long time for the video to get to anything relevant to reviewers.

It might make sense to change the reviewer guidelines as there are a few things these don't mention which are still important for reviewing IMO but integrating everything from the post I wrote might be too much in addition to the existing reviewer guidelines. In any way, I think it might make sense to create a distinct MSO post for changing the help center.

Looks like the 6-to-8 is closer to weeks this time, nice.

Apparently, I was one of the commenters you tried to talk to and who didn't answer (I routinely ignore invitations to chat rooms). I have a personal rule for continuing to participate on the network: I only do what I enjoy doing.  That leads to a secondary rule: No curation. I don't vote, I don't edit posts (except my own), and I certainly don't participate in Staging Ground.
I would appreciate an option to opt out of Staging Ground. Either don't show me any Staging Ground questions or show them with the normal question interface. I found it very annoying that I had to deal with a different interface because of something I don't want to participate in.

I wouldn't say it's necessary to use that option, I was mainly informing some users since I think most users are confused by this. If you don't want to see Staging Ground posts in the list, you can opt-out of it in your SO preferences

OK. Thanks. I could swear I had looked for that but it seems I overlooked the setting.
